# Delete a row from database at a specific time

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, cron

User can insert a row in the table 'timetable', which includes start and end time of the lecture.

```
INSERT INTO `timetable`(`Lab`, `start`, `end`, `Day`, `Lecture`, `Student`, `T_ID`) 
    VALUES ('$lab','$stime','$etime','$day','$lec','$class','$ID')
```

I want the row to automatically delete once the lecture is over, that is the current time is equal to the end time of the lecture.

One way to do that (which I found somewhere in the net) is to use mysql events

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
CREATE EVENT delete_event
   ON SCHEDULE AT '2016-27-2 08:00:00'
   ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
  DO
    BEGIN
      DELETE FROM `timetable` WHERE (`Lab`= $lab, `start`, `end`, `Day`)
    END;
```

But the problem is, I can't pass php variables in place of schedule time.
Something like this.

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
CREATE EVENT delete_event
   ON SCHEDULE AT '<?php echo($etime)?>'
   ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
  DO
    BEGIN
      DELETE FROM `timetable` WHERE (`Lab`= $lab, `start`, `end`, `Day`)
    END;
```

Another solution I found to this problem is to create a cron job (I'm not familiar with this at all). As far I understood about this, this can be done using cpanel (or any other control panel) in the hosting server. 
But what if I'm using a localhost ?
Is there any other way to manually create a cron job without using any control panel (maybe using event scheduler ?)

If there is any other way to solve this problem, I'm all ears. I'm a noob at coding, so if this is a silly question please forgive me, but do answer !

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to remove the data? If anything they can serve as statistics. Only display the events after `start` column time would be a viable option.

Comment: yes, I want to remove the data from the table because that row is a temporary change in the timetable (like an extra lecture), once the lecture is over, I don't want it to remain in the database (since it's not part of the regular timetable).

Answer (score 0):

create a cron.bat file with example line C:\xampp\php\php.exe -f C:\xampp\htdocs\somwhere.php > C:\xampp\htdocs\somwhere.log and use windows event scheduler

Comment: What if Visrozar is on Linux? What if Visrozar do not use xampp in folder C:\xampp?

Comment: I stated example line, he didnt say what localhost he is using or what OS.

Comment: It is more likely he is on Linux since a cron-job is Linux specific only. On windows they are called scheduled tasks. If its on Linux most distro's have their own way of adding cron-jobs.

Comment: I'm using xampp and windows OS, but I didn't quite understand the answer you gave (maybe because I'm too weak in coding), can you give me an example code or a link wherein I can read more about it ?

Comment: Visrozar, create a text file for example cron1.txt, place C:\xampp\php\php.exe -f C:\xampp\htdocs\yourscript.php > C:\xampp\htdocs\yourscript.log, then rename cron1.txt to cron1.bat so it can become an executable, then use it on windows Task Scheduler. search Task Scheduler on the start up menu.

Answer (score 0):

You could try repeated events. For example

```
CREATE EVENT
ON SCHEDULE
  EVERY 1 DAY
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO
  BEGIN
    DELETE FROM `timetable` WHERE (`day` < NOW())
  END;
```

Look at the doc: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html

Comment: I want the row to be deleted as soon as the lecture time is up, if the schedule will check only once a day, it won't be able to delete on time and there can be almost 24 hrs delay.

Comment: Then you have to make the shedule tighter ;)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to add your event (like this one you have already, but without `ON COMPLETION PRESERVE`) in the same script, when you add your temporal data. This can happen, just like any other query on the database.

Comment: I'm adding the event in the same script, still the question is, how can I send a specific time to run the event (not just timestamps).

and as far as I know, on completion clause only prevents server to automatically delete a clause once the event is expired. I don't see why removing that will be helpful. (I'm a noob !)

Comment: You are inserting inside a php script right? So additional to firing ``$db->query("INSERT INTO timetable(`Lab`, `start`, `end`, `Day`, `Lecture`, `Student`, `T_ID`) 
    VALUES ('$lab','$stime','$etime','$day','$lec','$class','$ID')")`` you have to execute ``$db->query("CREATE EVENT delete_" . $ID " . "
   ON SCHEDULE AT '$day $etime'
  DO
    BEGIN
      DELETE FROM `timetable` WHERE `Lab`= $lab
    END;")``